# Prove special case of Brianchon's theorem using inversion

Tags: geometry, circles, polygons, inversive-geometry

[Brianchon's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brianchon's_theorem) says:

> When a hexagon is circumscribed around a conic section, its principal
>   diagonals (those connecting opposite vertices) meet in a single point.

From [interactive demo](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/Brianchon.shtml): (found at [www.cut-the-knot.org](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/))

[image]

---

The problem is to prove following special case:

> When a hexagon is circumscribed around a **circle**, its principal
>   diagonals meet in a single point.

However, the requirement is to ***use inversion***.

I don't have the right idea, could you help?